# reinitialise angular reactive form with updated values / array

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

I have Angular Reactive form with nested array which is working fine. but the issue is if user go back to previous page and change some value and then come back to form page the values are not getting updated.

Scenario:

Selects 2 users on page 1 and go to page 2.

Form initialise with 2 user forms as array.

Now go back to page 1 and add 1 more user and go to page 2

still showing 2 forms it should show 3 form for users.

Comment: Can you include some code? What did you try to resolve this issue? Did it work? If not why? Do you have any errors? If yes, include them here.

Comment: let me create a stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to subscribe to the valuechanges of the form to update the values of the fields that change?

Comment: More of a comment rather then an answer